# Expo Camera - Development Build "This app is missing NSCameraUsageDescription"

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I'm using the command expo run:ios to build my app on the phone using Expo's development build. I am also using the expo-camera component. However, when I navigate to the page with the camera, I get the following error from Expo.

> "This app is missing NSCameraUsageDescription, so video services will
> fail. Add this entry to your bundle's Info.plist"

[image: screenshot of error]

**What I've tried**

I've tried adding "NSCameraUsageDescription" as a key in `app.json` as a child of "ios" > "infoPlist" > "NSCameraUsageDescription." However, I noticed the Info.plist generated in ios/expo/ still does not contain NSCameraUsageDescription.

I've also tried deleting the ios folder and rebuilding the project, but the problem still exists.